# to get value from any GridView Row (not only selected)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying with this code. But it doesn't work. What is wrong?

Picture for Question:

[image]

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView4.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBox2.Text += GridView4.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString() + ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: What does not work in your code? Do you get exception error?

Comment: is there any value added to TextBox2.Text? need to update your question with a little more than "it does not work, what is wrong" ideally with Expected Results == foo and actual results == bar and this is what is in the data grid"

Comment: There is no error. When i clicked Buton1 appear output in textbox ", , , ". Which contained tree line gridview.

Comment: I've add picture.

Comment: You have controls in your `Cell[1]`. Instead of `Text` try to `FindControl("MyLabel")` and use it.

Answer (score 1):

- You have to `FindControl` inside GridView and cast it e.g. `Label`.
- Add values to `List<string>`
- Join list by comma `,`

In workaround:

```
List<string> valueArray = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < GridView4.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // Label1 is ID of your control in GridView
    string value = ((Label)GridView4.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("Label1")).Text;
    valueArray.Add(value);
}
TextBox2.Text = string.Join<string>(",", valueArray); // seperate values by ,
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following line

```
 TextBox2.Text += GridView4.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + ", ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button_SonucKaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{// I did with Asif.Ali and  Alex Kudryashev's opinion.
    try
    {    
         OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(VTYolu);
         con.Open();
         foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView4.Rows)
         {
             Label innerLabel = (Label)row.FindControl("Label1x");
             DropDownList innerDropdown = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList1x");
             TextBox innerTextBox = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox4x");

             string Ekle1 = "UPDATE Dat_Odev SET OdevKontrolTarihi=@Tarih, OdevSonucu=@Sonuc, SonucAciklama=@Aciklama WHERE Kimlik=@id";
             OleDbCommand Komut1 = new OleDbCommand(Ekle1, con);
             Komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tarih", DateTime.Now.ToString());
             Komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sonuc", innerDropdown.SelectedValue);
             Komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Aciklama", innerTextBox.Text);
             Komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Int32.Parse(innerLabel.Text));
             Komut1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception HataKodu)
    {//Hata oluştuğunda çalışacak kodlar
        Label_Hata.Visible = true;
        Label_Hata.Text = "Ödev sonuçlarını kaydederken bir hata oluştu. Veya Veritabanı hatası. Sistem yöneticisi ile irtibata geçiniz. (Hata kodu: " + HataKodu + ")";
    }
}
```